# Compare OS X with Ubuntu

Tags: macos, ubuntu, comparison

I should write a study, comparing two operating systems. My choice was OS X and Ubuntu, especially because the last Ubuntu, 11.11 (Oneiric Ocelot) seems to be as OS X Lion. 
  This two themes are too large - I would like to be more specific in my study - such as kernel or thread differences. Can you suggest me some ideas, which are large enough to write a study about them, but specifically good enough in the same time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some ideas to investigate:

- license and freedom of software (and of user data).
- the `/proc` filesystem
- kernel limitations (number of threads, of processes, of inodes, max file sizes)
- availability of cross platform framework libraries (like Qt)
- hardware drivers & heterogeneity
- thread implementations
- dynamic libraries, plugins
- graphical interfaces
- availability of language implementations

etc etc